# Teradata / SQL join data conversion

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

This has been racking my brain for the entire afternoon, and I feel like I am missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

I have two table, A and B. Table A has a column called A_id, and it has type DECIMAL(16,0). Table B has a column called B_id, and it has type varchar(100). I am trying to an inner join, ideally from A to B. After that, I also need to filter the result with a where clause, such as A = 12345. So far, I have tried below things.

```
select A.A_id, B.B_id 
from A 
join B on B.B_id = cast(cast(A.A_id as bigint) as archer(100))
where A_id = '12345';
```

(I also tried cast A,A_id directly to varchar)

This doesn't produce any error, but it returns no result. I know they are same A_id and B_ids.

Furthermore, below code works and return good result

```
select A.A_id, B.B_id 
from B 
join a on B.B_id = A.A_id
where B_id = '12345';
```

If I take out the `where` clause, then sql will return `error message (2620)` suggesting that I have bad character. Similarly, if I don't do any casting, sql will return error message. I assume there are some sort of implicit casting going on that made the second chunk of code work.

I really need help on how to make the first chunk of code work. So, how to `cast` `A.A_id` correctly so the join will actually work.

Comment: I don't get what the question is.  Your last query seems to work.  So, use that version.

Comment: I would prefer to make the first chunk of code work, select from A and join B. Also, as I mentioned, the second chunk of code will not work when I remove the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare a numeric and a character value the string will always be casted to a Float (which is the most flexible numeric format), see [Implicit Type Convesions](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_151K/IMPLICIT_TYPE_CONVERSIONS.html).

Your double cast simply removes the period which is part of the default format of a Decimal, and results in a string '12345' instead of '12345.'.

Obviously there's some bad data in table B which can't be casted to a numeric and the `where B_id = '12345'` removes that before the cast.

Of course it's a wrong data model when you have to join two columns with different data types, less efficient and statistics are lost.

As a workaround you can apply

```
on TO_NUMBER(B.B_id) = A.A_id -- TD14+
```

or

```
on TRYCAST(B.B_id AS DECIMAL(16.0)) = A.A_id -- TD15.10+
```

Both return NULL for bad data, but don't fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table A
(
a_id decimal (16,0)
);

create table B
(
b_id varchar(10)
);

insert into A select 12345;
insert into B select '12345';

-- produces result
select A.a_id, B.b_id from A join B on a.a_id=b.b_id;

--produces the same result, although I don't understand the reason for intra-casting
select A.A_id, B.B_id from A 
  join B on B.B_id = cast(cast(A.A_id as bigint) as varchar(100))
where A_id = '12345';
```

The reason it didn't produce the result for you may be because you inserted an extra, let's say, blank character into table B's id, and that doesn't compare correctly. Id est: ' 12345'<>'12345'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding left trim and also right trim before casting. The result still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you cast in reverse then? cast(B.b_id as decimal(16,0))